# what is the value of $x$ such that $x^{180i} = -1$, where $i$ is the complex unit

Tags: complex-numbers

since $e^{\pi i} = -1$, the coefficent of $i$ in $e^i$ is the rotation from $(1, 0)$ about $(0, 0)$ on the complex plane, in radians, the value of $x$ for $x^{180i} = -1$ would be useful for doing rotations on the complex plane, in degrees. (I am aware that I could do $e^{\frac{2pi\theta}{360}i}$ to do rotations in $\theta$ degrees, but there is some learning experience and time saved in working out this value "$x$"

EDIT: $x$ is any value that satisfies $180\ln(x)=(2n+1)\pi, n \in \Bbb Z $

One such example is $1.01760649121...$ or $(e^{\pi/180})$.

Comment: @Rushy Such formulae are very tempting but not always correct in the complex world

Comment: $x^{180i}=e^{ln(x)180i}$  So $ln(x)180= (2n+1)\pi$ for any $n$.

Comment: $\exp(2\pi i\cdot i)=\exp(-2\pi),\,(\exp(2\pi i))^i=1^i=1$ If we use the principal branch. As it turns out, one (of the countably infinitely many) value of $1^i$ *is* $\exp(-2\pi)$, but this is not the principal value @Rushy

Comment: I'd first solve for (x^i) in (x^i)^180 = -1 the solve for $x$.

Comment: George, to emphasise on Herb’s comment: @herbsteinberg shows that in fact there are infinitely many such $x$!

Comment: @FShrike thankyou for the help on this question. if so, what are the valid values for x

Comment: Any! Literally any that satisfy herb’s condition $\ln(x)\cdot180=(2n+1)\pi,\,n\in\Bbb Z$. One such $x$ would be $\exp\left(\frac{\pi}{180}\right)$; you may find infinitely many alternatives, and the one I just suggested would be the principal such $x$.

Comment: Elementary algebra: $x=e^{\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{180}}$.  for any integer $n$.

Comment: so the easiest value for $x$ is ~$1.01760649121$! thank you @FShrike for the quick answer!

Comment: The definition of $a^b$, for arbitrary complex numbers, is $\exp(b\cdot\ln(a))$ - recall that this really is: $\exp(b\operatorname{Log}(a))\cdot\exp(b\cdot2\pi i n),\,n\in\Bbb Z$ and you can take any branch of exponentiation, with the first multiplicand being the principal value. This is always the thing to remember for these questions, and don’t fall into traps like $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ is any value that satisfies $180\ln(x)=(2n+1)\pi, n \in \Bbb Z $

One such example is $1.01760649121...$ or $(e^{\pi/180})$.

Please suggest a letter for this value as it may be useful.

Comment: We need not suggest a letter, as I highly doubt this is a constant of any particular interest! I edited your post with backslashes: `\ln,\pi` renders those symbols properly, and using a backslash will work for almost any standard symbol in MathJax. People do sometimes answer their own posts, but I’d say that since you embedded a question with it, it would be better to make this an edit on your original question.

Comment: @FShrike why should i not put the answer to the question in the answer section? and why would this constant not be useful.

Comment: If a question has been answered in the comments, it is usually the commenter’s responsibility to write this up as an answer. Were your question much more complicated, then it would not be out of place to write up the answer for yourself once you’ve figured it out (I have done this perhaps three times myself, for the benefit of other students) but the answer here is really very brief and contained in one comment, which is why another user than myself decided to downvote. Numerically $\exp(\pi/180)$ does not seem a likely contender for anything much, it seems just a number at best.

Comment: @FShrike aren't all constants just numbers?

Comment: Philosophically yes I suppose, one could argue this. However, consider $e,\pi,\gamma,\zeta(-2),\cdots$ (my list is quite boring because I do not study number theory or constant-heavy thing) - you can rest assured mathematics is full of commonly occurring and interesting constants; I can personally rest assured that $\exp(\pi/180)$ has not been theoretically studied, or come up notably in any two places. All constants are just numbers, but some constants are beautiful numbers, or magical ones, or fascinating ones, or ... you see?

Comment: Proving a negative is hard, but I don't see why $e^{\pi/180}$ is more important than $e^2$.

Comment: @FShrike ...or useful ones, Like a value that allows you to rotate in degrees on the complex plane.